# Select value from dictionary table in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, mapping

I have a table (data) where I need to insert a value from a reference from another table (dictionary). The dictionary has the form:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

and the data has the form

| something else | value |
| --- | --- |
| some stuff | A |
| ... | B |
| ... | A |
| ... | B |
| ... | C |
| ... | C |
| ... | B |
| ... | B |
| ... | A |

Both data and dictionary tables are in different tabs. What I need to get is a way to add a column in data table in such a way to match id and value. In the example the result should be:

| something else | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| some stuff | A | 1 |
| ... | B | 2 |
| ... | A | 1 |
| ... | B | 2 |
| ... | C | 3 |
| ... | C | 3 |
| ... | B | 2 |
| ... | B | 2 |
| ... | A | 1 |

I tried to search some functions like MAP() but it does not do what I need. This is basically a mapping operation but I'm not finding a function that can do the job, do you know something that can be useful for this?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOOKUP` formula does the job.

| something else | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | A | =LOOKUP(B2; dictionary!$B$2:$B$4; dictionary!$A$2:$A$4) |

where `$B$2:$B$4` takes A, B and C (values column) and `$A$2:$A$4` takes 1, 2 and 3 (id column).

You can check [the documentation for this formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?sjid=9947787784593133348-EU)

Hope it helps someone else.

---

*Disclaimer: Even when this solution is marked as accepted because it actually solved my problem, it's worth to note the answer by [Harun24hr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77020088/5310721) and the comment by [z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17887301/z)*

Comment: LOOKUP is designed to work with sorted ranges and it may not return an exact match. You should use XLOOKUP instead.

Answer (score 1):

`MAP()` function should work with `XLOOKUP()`. Try-

```
=MAP(E6:E14,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,B2:B,A2:A)))
```

Adjust the formula for other TAB ranges.

[image]